# Move and scale image in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an image tag, size 100x75. The image it is holding is scaled down from 150x112. I don't want the image scaled down, that much, but I still want the container img tag to be 100x75, thus cliipping off some of the outer parts of the image. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
css:
.wrapper {
    width    : 100px;
    height   : 75px;
    overflow : hidden;
}

html:
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="...">
</div>
```